# Sequelizer and Google Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL): The server does not support SSL connections

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ssl, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm attempting to migrate my sequilizer models in my Node.js/Sequelizer application to my PostgreSQL database hosted on Google Cloud.  Note: GCP requires that I connect using SSL (or some complicated proxy).

When I run the following command: `NODE_ENV=production npx sequelize db:migrate` I get the error:

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 19.0.0, CLI: 6.6.0, ORM: 6.29.3]

** config.js **
Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Using environment "production".

**ERROR: The server does not support SSL connections**
```

P.S. This is my first time using Sequelizer and Google Cloud SQL.  I appreciate any help.

I can connect using my certificates over SSL on Postico2 (which affirms is a TLS 1.3 connection when it connects) and also used BeeKeeper Studio to connect as well.  In GCP console, I have it set to require SSL connection only (I'll require this for my project).

I'm also using the .sequelizerc setup to override the config to call my config.js (only way to work around other challenges loading the certificates):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

console.log("** config.js **");

module.exports = {
  development: {
    dialect: "sqlite",
    storage: "./database_dev.sqlite3"
  },
  test: {
    username: process.env.CI_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.CI_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.CI_DB_NAME,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432,
    dialect: 'postgres'
  },
  production: {
    username: process.env.PROD_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PROD_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PROD_DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.PROD_DB_HOSTNAME,
    port: process.env.PROD_DB_PORT,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    ssl: true,
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        require: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'..','ssl','server-ca.pem')),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'..','ssl','client-cert.pem')),
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'..','ssl','client-key.pem'))
      }
    },
    debug: true
  }
};
```

Dev and Test both migrated successfully.

**Update 3/21/2023**

As suggested below, I attempted to connect using:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, Pool } = require("pg");

const config = {
    user: process.env.PROD_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PROD_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PROD_DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.PROD_DB_HOSTNAME,
    port: process.env.PROD_DB_PORT,
    application_name: "sequelizer-practice",
    // this object will be passed to the TLSSocket constructor
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/ssl/server-ca.pem").toString(),
        key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/ssl/client-key.pem").toString(),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/ssl/client-cert.pem").toString(),
    },
};

const client = new Client(config);
client.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("error connecting", err.stack);
    } else {
        // console.log("connected");
        client.query("SELECT NOW()", (err, res) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(res);
            client.end();
        });
    }
});

const pool = new Pool(config);
pool.connect()
    .then((client) => {
        console.log("connected");
        client.release();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error("error connecting", err.stack))
    .then(() => pool.end());
```

This connected and returned the requested timestamp from the database.  But I still cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong with Sequelizer in trying to do the same thing.

Comment: That is regrettably terse error message.  Can you just try to connect with a simple node program without involving sequelize?

Comment: @jjanes, I was thinking the same thing.  I even had to add the console.log just to track down that this went through config.js to whatever was calling it but I can't determine if it's sequelize (I'm thinking not) or something further down the rabbit hole.  I'm thinking it's just the poor way sequelize is outputting through its error handling since I got a similar message when the certificates gave me a "PEM - no start line" kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue (though it's not so straightforward).  After reading the comments in this post on the Sequelizer Discussion on Github, I learned that the options are supposed to be passed directly to pg as-is.  Since I got it working with pg, I was able to narrow down the differences.

[Connect to postgres with ssl mode #15636](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/discussions/15636)

It turns out the way Sequelizer is picking up the variables for the Production config was having issues using the values from .env

When I hardcoded the strings for Username, Database, Host and Password directly into config.js, it resolved the issue.

One lesson for me, the IP Address won't come over as a string from an environment variable.  But note, this on its own, did not fix the problem.  I had to hardcode username and database as well or it tried to connect with my OS Username.